# Como poderia mudar o css do background do pai de um menu?

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou usando boostrap. Gostaria de mudar o "meu-parent" do menu com CSS, quando ele estiver com a classe "collapse.in":

```
<nav class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 pull-left meu-parent">
    <div class="menu-dropdown-test"> <!-- collapse.in só aparece quando ele está com o collapse ativo, acontece logo aqui abaixo:  -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left menu-webapp-v2">
                <li><a href="/webapp/home"><i class="item-leitura"></i><span>Leitura</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/webapp/conquistas"><i class="item-conquistas"></i><span>Conquistas</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/webapp/a-producao-textual"><i class="item-producao-textual"></i><span>Produção textual</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-close"><a href="/webapp/sair"><i class="item-sair"></i>Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Há alguma forma de fazer o css do collapse.in funcionar para um parent > parent? Pois preciso mudar o fundo para um preto com opacidade 0.6 quando o dropdown do menu estiver aberto (com collapse.in).

Comment: Acho que vc só pode mudar elementos filhos, e não pais. Talvez seja possível fazer isso jQuery.

Comment: Preciso de certeza nesta informação.

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rápida aqui e é **certeza** que não tem como selecionar elementos-pai no CSS, como eu já achava. Tem como recorrendo ao JS.